# Escaping square brackets in element's name when using the Attribute Equals Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Please consider the following code:

`$('[name='+temp[i][0]+']').prev().addClass('form_error');`

where temp[i][0] is an array item holding the name of a form field which contains square brackets (as it represents a checkbox array),  `name_of_field[]`.

In order for this to work I know I should escape the square brackets in the form field's name. However, since I'm a newbie to regular expressions, I can't seem to get it right. Could anyone provide me with the proper code? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just quote the value, and escape the quote:

```
var name = temp[i][0];
name = name.split('"').join('\\"');                   // Escaped " is \\"
$('[name="'+name+'"]').prev().addClass('form_error');
```

This also accounts for other valid name, but invalid selector characters, such as `$`.

If you really want to use a RegEx, this following is sufficient (deliberately used a one-liner to show that short code is not always readable):

```
$('[name="' + temp[i][0].replace(/"/g, '\\"') + '"]').prev().addClass('form_error');
//            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: This works, but it should be noted that using the '[' and ']' characters in an HTML name or id is invalid (and therefore, is not guaranteed to keep working): http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name

Comment: @Vincent: True, they are not standard, but they have been used *for ages* to send data as "array" to PHP. [In HTML5, `name` can basically have any value, so it is guaranteed to work](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/attributes-common-to-form-controls.html#attributes-common-to-form-controls): *"Any non-empty value for `name` is allowed, but the names "_charset_" and "isindex" are special[...]"*.

Comment: @Felix: Tried various RegEx solutions found on the internet (among which some at SO), but since my RegEx skills are (still) very poor, I musta made mistakes implementing them in my own code :\ ... Thanks for helping me out. Works flawlessly :)

Answer (score 0):

I thought I might clarify this, as I will no doubt be going back to this issue again.

The above problem may be best solved with the above 'regular expression' replacement, however, if you are just trying to access a statically named element(s) like below, then here is your simple guide:

```
<input type="text" name="mytextelement[]" />
<input type="text" name="mytextelement[]" />

<script>
//using vanilla javascript

document.querySelector('[name="mytextelement\[\]"]'); //gets the first element only

document.querySelectorAll('[name="mytextelement\[\]"]'); //gets an array of above elements

//using jQuery

$('[name="mytextelement\[\]"]'); //gets all elements

<script>
```